# SSRS Report in Web App clearing out Session variables?

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

We're using a SSRS report with URL links that's being displayed in our web application.  When we click on a link in the report, it should take you to a page within the web app.  However, when we click on the link (link created using SSRS Action property), it appears to be clearing out the session variables.  The web app gives the error that we are "no longer logged in".

Any ideas as to how to go about fixing or debugging?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: How exactly are you displaying the SSRS report in your web application?

Comment: We're using the ReportViewer 10.0 .NET control to display the report.

Comment: Are SSRS and the web app on the same server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that they are on different servers:
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/knowledgecast/the-double-hop-problem)